# Flutter progress bar with spaced slots

Tags: flutter

Is there a progress bar control like below for flutter? Is it possible to change the LinearProgressIndicator to look like this?

[image]

Comment: It would be easy enough to create an overlay image that you could drop on top of a `LinearProgressIndicator` to make it look like this, but it depends on if you want it to behave like a segmented progress bar or merely look like one. Although you could simulate a segmented behavior by updating the progress bar's value in increments instead of continuously.

Comment: You could find a solution using this plugin
step_progress_indicator
https://pub.dev/packages?q=progress+indicator